# Dealing with outdated questions with incorrect answers

Tags: discussion, old-questions, wrong-answers, outdated-information

I recently came across a baffling, transient issue on one of my systems. It self resolved (or I accidentally fixed it), but I'd documented one of the symptoms of the issue while troubleshooting which I'd like to know about.

As a good Stack Exchange denizen, I looked up this issue and found a question with a similar issue which is from almost 12–13 years ago on one of the sites I frequent. It has an answer with a +1 which is incorrect and as someone who was seeing the *actual* problem, I felt there was a misunderstanding of what was wrong based on the information given. The answer wasn't accepted, nor is there any replies from the OP.

This leads me to an interesting problem — I can't ask a new question because it'd be a duplicate yet the existing question is useless to anyone in its current state.

The existing answer, IMO is *actively misleading*, but moderators do not delete answers for being 'wrong' and it's harmless — and regular users need a certain amount of co-ordination to delete. As an old obscure question, chances are no one cares. I've somewhat clearer documentation of the issue, but I'm certain my environment is different from OPs and even if I could replicate the issue, it might not be the same root cause — but I don't know. I'm also unlikely to get feedback from the other question's OP.

On the other hand, I'm not confident that a bounty *would* get an answer due to the obscure nature of the issue.

I've commented on the answer *but* 13 years on, I doubt the person posting the answer would remember either.

Comment: Is there reason to believe that a new question wouldn't follow the same path of fading into obscurity, creating a "new standard to replace the rest of them" problem? if not... simply applying a bounty would likely have a better effect than asking a new question, assuming you're posting on a stack where bounties get looked at and the context of the question perfectly matches yours. If you have new context to provide, then it's likely not a duplicate anyway.

Comment: There is not. - my only 'advantage' is that without answers it'll get roombaed, and in the short term, while my memory is still fresh I can look at things and update it. I ended up talking the user who posted the answer to the older question into deleting it eventually. In an ideal world, since the system is not in 'production' I'd replicate the issue and work with folks to try to resolve it, but its not an ideal world

Comment: In an ideal world the answer would be correct, ;)

Comment: I'm a realistic idealist . And if I already had a correct answer, I wouldn't have to ask a question about what do it. I'd read it, nod my head, and be a little more enlightened :D

Answer (score 7):

It seems you both require that this is a duplicate and say that it is not, simultaneously. Seems like the crux of your problem.

You say that you can't ask a new question because it would be a duplicate of the existing one. That said, you say you're certain your environment is different and has a different root cause. After 12-13 years, that seems quite likely.

Assuming all of this is correct, I don't see how it can be both a duplicate and not simultaneously. While I won't dictate which path to take, either accept that it's not a duplicate and ask a new question, or accept that it is and write an answer.

A question can be written to say "I did find this very similar question but the answer there is wrong and after 12 years my system is likely so different that the solution to that user's problem would not be the same as the solution to mine."

Alternatively, an answer can be written as "It's 12 years later and I had the same issue. While I can't be certain it's a solution to the question asked, what worked for me is..."

Another option would be to determine if the question contains enough detail to be closed - you say that you wouldn't get feedback from the OP, is that indicating that it's missing information that would help you confirm whether or not your systems are the same?

I don't know that there's one "right" answer but I'm still quite confused how a question can both be a duplicate and not at the same time.

Comment: Aside from some of the solutions ending up being conflict of interest is really(I can't delete someone's answer cause I didn't *like it*) , without an upvoted *incorrect* answer, the original question would go away.  I think the crux of the issue for me is the incorrect answer. I did end up asking the question - referencing the other one and why the answer was wrong, but its still likely what people will find in the same situation *first*

Answer (score 2):

It's very hard to talk about this without a concrete example.

For example, on a site like Stack Overflow, 12 years ago you would be talking about Java 7 or Ruby 2, not Java SE 20 or Ruby 3.2 that are the most recent today. When you're talking about programming languages and frameworks, the best answers for Java 7 or Ruby 2 haven't changed that much since they came out, but those answers are not necessarily applicable or even correct for Java SE 20 or Ruby 3.2. Making sure that the question has appropriate context is important so future readers know the context in which the answers apply.

However, on a site like Software Engineering or Project Management, things haven't changed drastically. Older answers could reference previous editions of publications, like ISO 12207:2008 instead of ISO 12207:2017 or the PMBOK Guide 4th Edition instead of the PMBOK Guide 7th Edition. In these fields, there are some fundamental shifts, but even then, a lot of new approaches or paradigms that shake up the field wouldn't necessarily invalidate an old answer, but just make it less appealing based on the latest information.

Defining what is meant by "incorrect" is important. Was it correct a decade ago? Did people at least perceive it as correct or the right way a decade ago, but new knowledge has led to alternatives? Or was it wrong then and remains wrong today?

If the question is one that has time as an important context (see my Stack Overflow question above), I would go with asking a new question and making the time-sensitive context clear between the two questions. If time isn't an important question, the correct thing to do would be to edit the question, vote on the answers, and leave comments for the posters and perhaps future readers so they understand the issues with any existing answers. Unfortunately, there may never be an answer. But if there ever is a correct answer shared, hopefully it finds its way to the SE network question, gets gobbled up by Google and other search engines, and people get directed there.

Comment: In this case, it was never correct. A "once" correct answer, that's obsoleted has value. I'm mostly on the superuser side of things, and I can't imagine DHCP (the core protocol in this case) for Ipv4 has changed much since SE started.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't know enough, but I'd say that either the original question has insufficient context and should either be edited to have the necessary context (which may or may not be the OP's context but yours) to allow someone to generate a good answer or closed to make way for your question. What's right depends on existing answers and the site culture, and I don't know the SU culture well enough to say for sure. I'd favor keeping the original and editing if it it doesn't invalidate any potentially right answers to preserve inbound links and shares.

Answer (score 1):

If you think an answer is incorrect then, unless you want to edit it to correct it, I think it should be considered not useful, and downvoted as your first step.

After that the ways to proceed could follow either of the paths suggested in [@Catija's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393306/215590).

Answer (score 1):

On tooling questions, the context is very relevant. If the question is old, it was not well written, and it might not be appropriate to make it canonical, I think it best for you to post a new question.

## Post a new question

Mention the old question, and explain what makes your context different from the context of the old question.

Asking about an obscure topic could be challenging. On one side, it might be thought to be uncertain about the attention the question might get and if it will get a helpful answer. Finding the proper writing style and detail might also be challenging, especially when you are familiar with your site's dynamics and aware of the dynamics of popular and niche topics. However, a question that is never posted will never get an answer.

A word of caution: Questions about obscure topics might become "abandoned questions" if they don't get upvotes and answers. Abandoned questions are automatically deleted, so prepare yourself to self-answer your question and promote your question to get attention among the people who might be interested in the topic of the question to get some upvotes to prevent your question from being automatically deleted.

## Wrong answer

Let's put the answer correctness and misleading part to a side for a moment.

Start by focusing on whether the answer is answering the question. First, you should have evaluated whether the question is irrelevant nowadays, i.e., if it depends on a third-party service that is no longer offered. If the question is obsolete, in most circumstances, it should be closed first, and then it could be deleted.

Remember that a question is not "obsolete" because it's about a product no longer available in stores. An old question might still be relevant if it's still reasonably possible that someone had a similar context, or the context is general enough so another person might find the question similar to something they might ask, i.e., despite that metrology technology has changed a lot, physical units like Volts, Amperes, among others are still valid.

If the question is OK, but the answer relies on something that is impossible to use nowadays or does not make sense, vote to delete it. Add a comment mentioning why objectively it can't be used nowadays. That criteria might be severe risks to health, security and privacy.

If the answer doesn't include things that might harm people and doesn't lead people to put in danger themselves and others, downvote and forget.

## Related

- [Preventing own question from being deleted as abandoned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284163/289691)